# Python doing addition without sum or numpy

Tags: python

I am very very new in Python and I am trying to create a new list out of two lists when I add the two. But I get an error message which I don't really understand why (see below). I cannot use sum or numpy because it is an assignement.

For addition I wrote:

```
x=[24,54,84]
y=[2]

def addition(x,y):
    a=len(x)
    for i in range(a):
    x[i]=x[i]+y
    return x[i]

print(addition(x,y))
```

the error message I get is:

```
  x[i]=x[i]+y
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Have you imported the `math` module?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide your desired output?

Comment: You're missing a tab for the line of code after `for`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question exactly? What are you trying to accomplish? Please read [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for debugging help, you need to add your expected output and actual output -- or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). Just saying "it doesn't work" is not descriptive enough; it's not clear if you're getting an `IndentationError` or if the output is not what you wanted. (Reference: [mre].)

Comment: Note that your code doesn't create a new list, it looks like it modifies `x`.

Answer (score -1):

```
x=[24,54,84]
y=[2]

def addition(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]+y[0]
    return x

print(addition(x,y))
```

Two thing where wrong:

1. Indent in the `for` item to loop (need to be spaced out to be in the for)
2. `return` ends the function, so return the vector instead once the loop is over
3. i made the correction as similar as I can to your code. This code rewrites `x`, so instead define another variable and return that variable if is what you want.

Things i changed:

1. `a` is not necessary, can be put in the `for` the `len` itself
2. i made the suposition that `y` is like a constant, you have defined it like a vector so i need to take the first item of the vector in each loop

EDIT: Here's the same code without modifing `x`, meaning you have a new vector in the addition function as you asked

```
x=[24,54,84]
y=[2]

def addition(x,y):
  temp = x.copy()
  for i in range(len(x)):
    temp[i] =x[i]+y[0]
  return temp

print(addition(x,y)) 
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: OP did say they're "trying to create a new list", not modify the existing one. If you do decide to modify the existing one, [it's better to not return it as well](/a/16641831/4518341).

Comment: True, you can put print(x) directly without returning, but i tried to be as close as possible with op code